# How to set default virtual server (sites-available) in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have 2 sites at my linode VPS. I configured ourdomain.com and mydomain.com in sites-available directory (/etc/apache2/sites-available/ourdomain.com.conf // mydomain.com.conf) and activated and restarted Apache.

There is a way to specify ourdomain.com as the main/default site? Because when I access through the ip, Apache shows mydomain.com :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache reads your vhost files in alphanumeric order, and the first one it reads becomes the default vhost in case none of the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directives match. See [Name-based Virtual Host Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) in the Apache docs.

So, for whatever domain you want to be "default", make sure that vhost file is listed first in the directory listing.